# jQuery: Cloned dropdown does not react to change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div cloned to a jQuery object, such as:-

`$dependent = $page.find("div[data-name=dependent]").clone();`

This `$page.find("div[data-name=dependent]")` is hidden i.e `display: none` in HTML.

Now the cloned `div` has a `<select>` which a obviously cloned too. I make a few modifications to the `$dependent` such as:-

```
$dependent.attr("data-name", "dependent-clone");
$dependent.find("a").attr("onclick", 'functionCall()');
```

No changes are made to the `<select>` .

Now when I append the cloned `div` i.e. `$dependent`, the dropdown does not display the changed values. It responds to the `onChange()` event but does not display the changed value.

I am using jquery-1.6.4.js and jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$dependent.find("a").attr("onclick", 'functionCall()');` ... please, please don't do this. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **working demo** :) http://jsfiddle.net/EGQEL/7/ (Please let me know if I missed anything)

Binding need to happen on the dynamic append use .on or .live in latest Jquery .on replaces .live

`.on` can be used instead of `.live`

also this will be helpful : http://jsfiddle.net/pbWEp/2/  Link==> [copy/Clone dropdown list with selected option in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861729/copy-clone-dropdown-list-with-selected-option-in-jquery)

**OR** http://jsfiddle.net/ZTF5J/2/ - link==> [drop-down clone add and remove using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756669/drop-down-clone-add-and-remove-using-jquery)

**OR** you can provide your jsfiddle I might take a look; **Please note** above jsfiddle is there to give you a tip :)

Hope this helps, have a nice one, cheers!